# When to scale? Measurements and metrics on the LAMP stack

Tags: performance, lamp

What are the biggest signs that a ( LAMP ) server is working too hard? Are there any metrics you take into consideration before beefing up your box or scaling out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely the most straight forward indicator is page loading speed? Google certainly put a lot of emphasis on it.

This will be affected by everything that goes into your system (disk io, network, physical memory, etc). So if your looking for a metric, this must be the one to monitor!

Comment: +1 - it doesn't matter if the server is running at 10% or 90% utilisation, or if you have 1 or 100 web servers - if your page load time is slow, end users will be unhappy!

Comment: Straight forward, yes. But would this lead you to a false sense of security? What if you observed satisfactory page load speeds but your server was just about to die?